# Is there any way to run a discord bot in specific hours of a day?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to run my discord.js bot in specific hours of a day like between 6:00 AM to 1:00 PM and then rest for 2 hours and start again from 3:00 PM to 10:00 PM rest again for 2 hours and then 12:00 midnight to 6:00 AM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this.

```
import { Client } from "discord.js";
const app = client
let doStuf = true

setInterval(async () => {
doStuf = !doStuf
if(doStuf) {
app.login(token)
} else {
app.destory()
}

}, 10000)
```

With this code, your bot is every 10s on and off. You can change the doStuf with a time function. That returns if at this time de bot needs to be offline or online.

Answer (score 0):

Any time a command is initiated, check the time and see if it is in those hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using this code

```js
setInterval(()=>{
  global.now;
  global.now = new Date().getHours();
}, 5000)

setTimeout(function(){

//you can repeat this code to make it run for different hours

if (global.now >= 6 && global.now <= 18) {

//code here... 

}else{
console.log('Time to Rest'.rainbow)
console.log(global.now)
}

}, 10000)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps future readers with the same problem.